# translating line of code from C# to IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ironpython

I need to convert this line of code from an asp.net c# page to asp.net IronPython, how would it be?

```
((IPostBackEventHandler)Button1).RaisePostBackEvent(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `Button1.RaisePostBackEvent(None)`.

Python, being a dynamic language, doesn't need the type specified, as it has no notion of casting. And `null` in Python is spelled `None`.

Comment: Although if you ever need to cast, you can use clr.Convert.